# I need to implement PI controller feedback to correct a distorted sinewave. A reference sine wave will be used in order to produce an error

Tags: c, feedback

I have converted DC to a nice 50Hz sinewave using a PIC microcontoller. I am using a H-bridge to create my sinewave. Modulated PWMs are being sent to my bridge. An LC filter on the output produces a 50Hz sinewave. When testing against non-linear loads, my original sinewave is becoming distorted. I need to implement a PI controller to fix the distortion, and restore the sinewave back to its original form using c code.

I have never implemented feedback control hence the confusion. Apologies.

```
PDC1 = lookup[b];
b++;
if (b==100) {
    b=0;
}
PDC2 = 1474-PDC1;
```

PDC1 sends the duty cycles from the look up table ranging from 0-100. These small PWMs give me my sine wave.

Comment: I don't know for sure that this is the wrong place, but this sounds like something you might get better feedback (ha) from at the ee site https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's also unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on electronics.stackexchange.com